# Python send() throwing "OSError: No error"

Tags: python, sockets

I operate a small size hosting company. Since a few months, more and more similar companies seem to get hit by those dns reflection/amplification denial of service. We were lucky enough to be avoided by these, at least for now. But I wanted to be prepared, so I found a Python script (I know a little bit of Python) and wanted to stress-test a few of my servers.

After I installed scapy, pypcap and all other dependencies, I'm getting an error traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python25\lib\threading.py", line 486, in __bootstr
   self.run()
 File "dnsdos.py", line 230, in run
   send(IP(dst=ns, src=self.target)/UDP()/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(
rbose=0)
 File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", lin
   __gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter,
unt,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
 File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", lin

   s.send(p)
 File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py"

   ifs = dnet.eth(iff)
 File "dnet.pyx", line 112, in dnet.eth.__init__
OSError: No error
```

Here is the problematic line of code:

```
send(IP(dst=ns, src=self.target)/UDP()/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname=A_record)), verbose=0)
```

Which leads to errors in \lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py on line 251, which is

```
__gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
```

and on line 234 which is

```
s.send(p)
```

and on \lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py on line 237 which is

```
ifs = dnet.eth(iff)
```

If needed, I can upload the entire code of these 3 files on pastebin or somewhere else.
I tried looking for what the problem is, but I can't figure it out. What I do think is that the arguments might be passed out wrongly. Can't say much, as only socket coding I did was way simpler that this.

OS: Windows 7 x64
Python 2.5

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: And what are the values of ns, self.target and A_Record

Comment: values for ns is a dns server (writted as IP) and A_Record I used mydomain.com

Comment: Could this be caused by using it on an x64 os ?